# Adding a background image to one route in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, ngroute

I built an app using angularJS 1. I only want to add a background image to the index, and for it to disappear when maneuvering to other routes. Any idea how I can do that without building a service?

Comment: The $route service has a `current` attribute allowing to know what the current route is. And angular has an ngClass directive allowing to add a CSS class depending on a boolean condition. Combine the two, and you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you could just use html for this purpose. Just insert `<img src="..."` into needed route's html page. 
If background image vary then set image source in scope variable as this in controller : `$scope.imageSrc="..."` and refer that as `<img src={{imageSrc}}`